Saving Pytorch model with specified activation function
I am trying to save my Pytorch model with its activation function used.
Here is a simple example
# define class for neural network
class NNM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_features, num_hidden):
        super(NNM, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(num_features, num_hidden)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(num_hidden, 1)
        
        self.saved_parameters = []
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.fc1(x))
        return self.fc2(x)
    
    def save_parameters(self):
        self.saved_parameters.append(copy.deepcopy(self.state_dict()))

# created model a few lines later

model = NNM(28, 100)

Here, the list saved_parameters and the function save_parameters will allow to save model's parameters in a list a specified location of training.
Using model.eval() just shows model's layers (input-hidden and hidden-output).
NNM(
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=28, out_features=100, bias=True)
  (fc2): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=1, bias=True)
)

What I need is something that integrates the used activation function.
NNM(
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=28, out_features=100, bias=True)
  (fc2): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=1, bias=True)
  (act_func): Sigmoid(fc1-fc2)
)

Or a simpler solution to save the activation function with related layers in a dictionary.

The simplest way to have an explicit structure when using a sequential architecture is to define all layers (including any linear or  flattening layers) in a nn.Sequential module:
class NNM(nn.Sequential):
    def __init__(self, num_features, num_hidden):
        super().__init__(
            nn.Linear(num_features, num_hidden),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
            nn.Linear(num_hidden, 1))

        self.saved_parameters = []

    def save_parameters(self):
        self.saved_parameters.append(copy.deepcopy(self.state_dict()))

Then your instance representation will be explicit:
>>> NNM(28, 100)
NNM(
  (0): Linear(in_features=28, out_features=100, bias=True)
  (1): Sigmoid()
  (2): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=1, bias=True)
)


The problem is that I have initiated a save_parameters list and a related function to deepcopy the state of my model. So I can have the parameters at each iteration (or at the beginning and ending of training) of my neural network.

Let me update my function

@pyaj, if the model was not defined as a sequential module, then there is no way to infer the order of execution of the layers just by looking at the state dictionary. If a layer (for example sigmoid) is not defined as an attribute to the nn.Module, then it will not show up in its representation string.

If I use nn.Sequential, can I create a list of deep copies of the model, like in my example? If yes, can you adapt your answer?

Of course, it will work the same way as with your model, as long as it is a nn.Module. See my edit above.
